# returning SQL rows and columns as variables

Tags: python, sql

I'm fairly new to python,

I'm trying to run a python script that connects to MySQL server.

The connection is fine, but when I execute a query to return a row, it spits out the entire row, but i want to sort the columns into python variables when returned so i can use those variables in the python script.

I'll be using a loop to do this.

Not sure why it has been hard to find this, i've been googling around but can't seem to find anything usefull as yet.

Does anyone know a simple way to sort out the returned columns into variables or multiple arrays?

Thanks

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  user="xxxxx",
  passwd="xxxxxx",
  database="vmware"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("select UserID, VMName FROM VM WHERE CommissionStatus='new';")


for x in mycursor:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over `mycursor`, you can just expand it to variables like shown in the [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html):

```
for (user_id, vmname) in cursor:
    print("{}, {}".format(user_id, vmname))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

So what if i was to use something like this?

user_id_variable = mycursor.user_id
vmname_variable = mycursor.vmname

or is it exclusive to the use or a loop?